# Mix python script with jave script for html

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to build up my personal project and wish to have a website that could have some interactivity with one of the applications I wrote in python script. Currently, my personal website is working and published, which is mainly using JaveScript as the scripting language. My question is: Is it possible that I could add python script onto the existing website without changing too much of the work that is being done already (index.html, etc.).

Comment: What do you want to achieve in python that you can't in javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can for example use uWSGI.